# MethodNotFoundException when adding a user control to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have two custom ListBox classes:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
public class MyCheckedListBox : ListBox
```

They're wrappers around the winforms `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` control to add a little implementation and styling etc.

I added the following code to each in order to remove the vertical scroll bar when necessary:

```
private const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
private bool verticalScrollbar = true;

[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool VerticalScrollbar
{
    get { return this.verticalScrollbar; }
    set
    {
        if (this.verticalScrollbar != value)
        {
            this.verticalScrollbar = value;
            this.RecreateHandle();
        }
    }
}

protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
        if (!this.verticalScrollbar)
            parms.Style &= ~WS_VSCROLL;
        return parms;
    }
}
```

I added one of each to an existing user control `ProfileGeneralPanel` and they worked as expected, by default the scrollbar is shown, setting the `VerticalScrollbar` property to false removes it. Although, now there's a need to use this arrangement in more than one place, so I'm extracting this structure to a seperate, new user control called `PrivilegesListView`. This new control has a single `MyCheckedListBox` and two `MyListBox` in a table. All three have `VerticalScrollbar` set to `false`. All is fine so far, the designer displays everything correctly.

However, when I attempt to drag this control from the toolbox onto another user control, an exception is thrown stating it cannot find the method: `MyCheckedListBox.set_VerticalScrollbar(Boolean)`

The method in question is obviously the generated method for a property. I've tried all the usuals, cleaned and rebuilt, restarted visual studio. Out of sheer desperation I also checked the IL generated when building, and the class `MyCheckedListBox` does indeed have that method defined. Any ideas why it's not able to find it?

**Note** that the designer for the control itself opens fine every time, it only has the issue when it is added to another form.

**Note** that the issue only occurs when `VerticalScrollbar` is set to false, either in the designer generated code for `PrivilegesListView` or hand-written in the constructor itself.

**Note:** Unfortunately at this stage it's not possible to use another control like a `DataGridView` instead of the list boxes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes wrong when you previously added the control to the Toolbox with the "Choose items" dialog.  That makes a *copy* of the control assembly, stored in a private directory where toolbox item assemblies are kept.  You can see this go wrong now perhaps, you are putting an *old version* of the control on your form, one that didn't yet have the added method.

The best way to avoid this trap is to let Visual Studio automatically add controls you are working on to the toolbox.  Make sure the setting is still correct, it tends to get changed by unwise attempts at improving VS perf.  Tools + Options, Window Forms Designer, General, AutoToolboxPopulate should be set to True.  Then any project in your solution that has a class that derives from Control or Component will have its controls automatically added to the top of the toolbox after you compile.  Changes you make to the control code are now always in sync.

In general, use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  It works just as well for VS as it does for your own programs.  You want to log all bindings so you also see the ones that succeeded but might have picked a copy of the assembly from the wrong folder.

Comment: Although an interesting post, I've not manually added anything to the toolbox. The two list boxes classes already existed, they were simply updated with the given code, and the new user control appeared in there automatically.

Comment: That doesn't leave much.  It is finding an old copy of the assembly somewhere, somehow.  You can use fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to get insight.

Comment: You are indeed correct, it was finiding an old copy of the assembly in one of our numerous output folders. If you'd like to add some words to that effect to your answer so I can go ahead and accept it. :)